# ReCaptcha v.2 validation in HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, validation, recaptcha

Sorry for the length of this question, but I wanted to include as much info as possible…

I have just taken over a project developing a responsive HTML5 site based on a template that uses jquery.validate.min.css and a related file (js.app) to validate form entries. The validator places warning messages below each form element if a required field isn't entered, or if an invalid email address is entered, etc., then processes the form.

I was asked to add Google's new ReCaptcha v.2 to the site's forms, but can't figure out how to add the appropriate client-side captcha validation within the template's existing validator. I have built a form that doesn't include the template's validators and it works perfectly, so I understand the basic concepts. I just need someone to point me in the right direction of adding the ReCaptcha validation script to the existing validation script(s).

Part of the issue is that ReCaptcha doesn't use the usual `<INPUT>` tag, and instead is built using a div, so the existing validators can't be easily modified to check the ReCaptcha status as they only run on the various input types of text, text area, etc.

Here is the code that properly renders the ReCapthca:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Login</title>
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer> </script>
<script>
function validateForm() {    
if (username == "") {
alert('Please provide a valid user name!');
username.focus();
return false;
}    
if(password.value == "") {
  alert("You must enter a valid password!");
  password.focus();
  return false;
}    
var v = grecaptcha.getResponse();
if(v.length == 0)
{
alert("You must solve the ReCaptcha!");
return false;
}
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
<form id="contact-form" name="contact-form" action="?" method="POST" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
<input type="text" id="username" name="username">
<div><input name="password" id="password" placeholder="password" type="password" required></div>
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="your_site_key"></div>
<br/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

When added to the template, however, the embedded script is over-ridden by the template which sends the forms to included files jquery.validate.min.css and a related file (js.app) to validate form entries. It does this even if I specify to run the script when the user submits the form with the usual onsubmit statement in the form tag.

The pertinent code from the app.js file is:

```
$("#contact-form").validate({
     ignore: ":hidden",
     rules: {
         username:{
            minlength: 6,
            maxlength: 12,
            required: true
        },
        password:{
            minlength: 6,
            required: true
        },

     },
     submitHandler: function (form) {
         $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "sendemail.asp",
             data: $("#contact-form").serialize(),
                error:function(){
                    //alert('asdasdasd');
                    console.log('Some thing went wrong! :D');
                    },
                    success:function(data) {
                    //alert(data);
                    if(data=='fail'){
                        $('#errormessage').html("<label for='captcha_code' class='error'>Security Code was incorrect.</label>");
                    }else{
                        $('.reg-form').html("<div id='message'></div>");
                         $('#message').html("<h2> Thanks for Submitting your Message!</h2>")
                             .hide()
                             .fadeIn(1500, function (data) {
                             $('#message').append("");
                         });
                    }
             }
         });
         return false; // required to block normal submit since you used ajax
     }
 });
```

I didn't copy and paste the jquery.validate.min.css file contents as it is fairly long, but you can grab a copy most anywhere on the 'net.

You will note that the template developer tried to handle Captchas when he developed the script, but it isn't working.

I have server-side validation on the form working, but would really like to work out a client-side validation too.

Thanks in advance for any help you kind folks might offer!

Comment: This seems like more of a question about validation.min than ReCaptcha

Comment: Thanks for the input Chuck. The question is probably actually about both the new ReCaptcha v.2 and validation.min, as well as the use of app.js in processing the validation and form input. Sadly, I still haven't figured out how to properly processes the validation of the new ReCaptcha using validation.min. It would be easy if the v.2 was still a form field that could be validated along with the rest of the form...